# How to fastest send Flashbot transaction?

Tags: flashbots

Flashbot transaction always delayed about 10 blocks.

Is there a way to confirm Flashbot transaction in `now_block_numer + 1` block?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to confirm Flashbot transaction in now_block_numer + 1 block?

No

Comment: But why this sniper bot buy the erc20 token  with `addLiquidity+0` block using flashbot? [tx here](https://etherscan.com/tx/0x2f003dc8c80127e037b6cc0ccf3a3ca420af86efeed872f237f2d97ffde19933)

Comment: do u find a sloution brother?